# How can STM32 on Maple Mini (leafLabs) be programmed using Keil?

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f10x

First of all I am not unfamiliar with embedded systems. Moreover, shame on me, I am an electronics engineer specialized in embedded systems.

The question I am asking is actually a little bit complicated. Thus, I will not ask it directly but explain my intention for your understanding.

`Maple Mini`, as some of you know, is a little development board based on `STM32F10x` arm processor. I intent to use it directly in my projects instead of designing a circuit for STM3210x processors.

Since my applications need to be real-time, fast and hardware oriented I do not want to use its own IDE. I need to use `Keil uvision`. (For instance, I am programming `Arduino Pro Mini` with `Atmel Studio`)

Now my question can be a little clearer, which is **as follows**.

**Since the processor on Maple Mini is a standard STM32F10x I need to be able to program it on any platform that is suitable for this MCU, but factors that are not related to STM32 itself prevent this." Can you briefly explain what causes the difference when it comes to programming different boards (but same MCU like STM32F10x) with different IDEs?**

Comment: The Keil uVision lists 459 devices for STM.  A quick check of web gives me this. http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/arm/st/stm32f10x/stm32f10x.h  So I'd say yes.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thank you, but the actual question is at the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On different boards with the same progamming interface (ie swd) it does not matter what board you're using. You should find SWCLK, SWDIO, GND, 3V3 pinouts on the board. All these pins are present on the MCU:

[image: from datasheet]

After finding, you should connect a programmer (ie ST-Link v2) to these pins. You should also install a driver for the programmer. In Keil - press Alt+F7, select Debug, select debugger in dropdown list (ST-link debugger), press settings, select port (SW). That's all.